# put select in a variable subquery return more than one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to put the following query in a variable but I have the error:

> "subquery return more than one value"

```
select (select count(cb) from pater b where b.cb=a.parent) AS test_pater 
from pater a
```

I would like to count the number of times parent value appears in cb column, and put the result in test_pater column for each row

expected results:

[image: expected results]

Comment: (1) This is only part of a query and is syntactically incorrect.  (2) Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Sorry, the query is:
 select (select count(cb) from pater b where b.cb=a.parent) AS test_pater
  from pater a
I would like to count the number of times parent value appears in cb column, and put the result in test_pater column for each row

Comment: . . Edit the question and put that information in the query.  Sample data and desired results would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reading between the lines on this one, but if your goal is to count the number of times each parent occurs in the "cb" column of that table, I think something like this will give you that.

```
select cb as parent, count (*) as occurrences_in_cb
from pater p
where exists (
  select null
  from pater c
  where p.cb = c.parent
)
group by cb
```

Depending on what you are doing with it, you might not need the semi-join ("exists clause").  That is only there to prevent cb entities that are not parents from being in the query results.

It will not, however, give you zero counts.  Wasn't sure if that was important or not, as it was listed in your example.  Short of understanding your use case, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Yes these are the results I want thank you
But how to put the entire query in a variable ? Because I want to generate the results thanks to a stored procedure, so the "select" option is not a good one

Comment: What DBMS are you using, and what do you mean store in a variable...  are you consuming this information in a program?  If so, what language?  Hopefully just a little more clarity if you can.  Can you show the stored procedure, for example (edit the original question to include)

Comment: Yes I am using sql server and I have to edit a stored procedure that will show these results when executed .
The procedure is big (it contains other queries) so I can't show it properly, but I just have to add this query .
Is it a bit clearer ?  Thank you for you help I am a beginner

Answer (score 1):

I've had to guess some at your table structure, but I think this may be what you want?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdc493/3

Creating your table structure

```
CREATE TABLE pater (cb int, parent int);
INSERT INTO pater VALUES 
(1,0), -- root
(2,1), (3,1), -- parent 1 has 2 children
(4,3), (5,3); -- parent 3 has 2 children
```

Your query

```
SELECT cb, (SELECT count(cb) FROM pater b WHERE b.parent = a.cb) as test_pater FROM pater a;
```

Results

```
| cb | test_pater |
|----|------------|
| 1  | 2          |
| 2  | 0          |
| 3  | 2          |
| 4  | 0          |
| 5  | 0          |
```